# Talking to daemons

Tags: c++, c, linux, daemon

I have seen lately a couple of programs that can be launched as daemons (e.g. linphonecsh) but also offer a second invocation method that will exchange information with the running daemon.  In the linpohone case, linephonecsh with one set of parms launches the daemon but if invoked with a different  set of parms it can query the status of the daemon (call in progress, call duration, hangup, exit, etc.).

So, since I need to write an app that could go either way, app or daemon, I was wonering about how one does this neat trick.  I suppose UNIX domain sockets would work as might named interprocess pipes.  D-bus perhaps?

And where might one see a good C/C++ example of this?

Any suggestion and alternate approaches are solicited.

Comment: Take a look at [boost's IPC stuff](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). I've only used plain old named pipes myself, because they're trivially easy to work with and I'm quite lazy.

Comment: It all depends on the usage pattern. For a rich command/response protocol, pipes or sockets would do. For heavy data exchange, shared memory. For really simplistic things like "reload the config" or "die now", signals would do.

Comment: You might also consider using D-Bus or SNMP

Comment: If you really want to talk to daemons safely I would suggest grabbing a copy of DIII.

Comment: Sorry, @Ed, but what's dlll (3 ells?).  A google lookup got all sorts of useless answers.  This is linux, not windows, just in case you meant dll.

Comment: Sorry, that was a (bad) joke.  DIII is Diablo III :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Shared memory
2. Pipes
3. UNIX domain sockets.

You should decide which one suits you best, based on the details of your task. I assume you're on Linux, so [a chapter from the book "Advanced Linux Programming" on inter-process communication](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch05-ipc.pdf) will help. It provides code examples, too.